# Mapping the primary key and foreign key

Tags: sql, database, datatable, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have created an employee table as

```
Emp_ID(Primary key), Emp_Name, Address,Designation,Manager_ID(Foreign Key).
```

Foreign key is mapped with the primary key. In manager id column I am entering the id of his/her manager. It means there will be many employee with same manager id.
Now the problem I am facing is it creates conflict between the employee id and manager id.

How will I maintain the database.

Comment: What do you mean by `maintain`?

Comment: Why do you want to make Manager_ID as the FK which refers to EMP_ID in the same table? If you need to refer the EMP_ID who reports to a manager, we can use self-joins.

Comment: suppose there an employee with employee id as 10 and manager id as 20 and he is the manager of a team. And there is another employee with employee id as 12 and he is reporting to manager id 20 and i need to enter his manager id in him manager id  column. Now the conflict occurs between the primary key and foreign key for employee id 12.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following insert query

```
INSERT INTO employee(Emp_ID, Emp_Name, Address,Designation,Manager_ID) values(1,"xyz","ABC","Engineer",(select manager_id from manager where id = 1))
```

Comment: Hi, don't hesitate to explain why it solves the problem and provide some links to the documentation ;)

Comment: As he is trying to enter the manager id into employee table which belongs in other table as foreign key. I thought it would help. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. It would be nice to have this all wrapped up in your answer, so that it makes a better documentation for others. Feel free to edit your answer as much as you like to make it more comprehensible ;)